# hibernate modelling many to many preserving integrity

Tags: hibernate, jpa, many-to-many

I'm trying to model a subset of my domain and I want to solve this problem as simply as possible in hibernate. See picture 1 for the basic modelling.

The problem with that is I can potentially associate whatever type, group and category to a property. Therefore I could store an invalid relationship between type, group and category.

So I think 3 is the correct way to model this, though I feel there will be too many tables to maintain and my hibernate will get a bit too complex.

Has anyone got any better ideas on how to model this in the DB and hibernate?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Can't you have:

```
@ManyToMany
private List<Group> groups;

@ManyToMany
private List<Type> types;

@ManyToMany
private List<Category> categories;
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I was thinking about doing exactly as you suggested. But then I thought that would potentially allow any combination of groups, types and categories on a property (not every group is related to a type etc). I would like to try and prevent that, if possible?